# SourceTree breaks Path variable

Tags: environment-variables, githooks, atlassian-sourcetree, clang-format

I started using `git-hooks` in my project, and one of precommit-hooks uses `clang-format`. 
On commit through SourceTree it fails to find clang-format.

`Error: 'clang-format' not found.`

But commit works, if I do this via terminal or via terminal inside SourceTree. After adding this line to git-hook, everything works in SourceTree.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

So looks like it doesn't work in SourceTree but I haven't found any bugreports about current version (Version 2.3.2)

Did I forget to enable some option somewhere in SourceTree or it should work by itself?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @JerryLee unfortunately, no. I had to move on and use another solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is still an issue

If using a Mac opening Sourtree from terminal with

```
open /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/MacOS/SourceTree
```

Fixes the issue by getting the correct path

Or you can change the pre-commit script and add the path there with something like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Alternate solutions can be seen in

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-Hook-failing-because-paths-don-t-seem-to-be-set/qaq-p/274792

Answer (score 2):

If you're using husky to manage git hooks, set the path from your terminal and retry. `echo PATH=${PATH} > ~/.huskyrc`

Since your terminal environment already has the right path set, this approach should hold until Atlassian actually fixes sourcetree bug.

Comment: No, I wasn’t using husky at the time.